# How do I enable text selection in Autodesk Forge Viewer with DWG as document

Tags: autodesk-forge

So I have a Forge Viewer correctly setup displaying my DWG/DXF.

I want to allow the user to click any Text or Multiline Text object and be able to handle a javascript event based on the selection.

For example, if you click on 1L2C in the Forge Viewer, a javascript event occurs with the selected item, thus allowing me to do a query to my API and display a popup.

The test file in question has a single Layout called "Layout 1" and is 2D.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The viewer doesn't have a "text selection" feature specifically, but you *can*:

- get notified when a certain element of your 2D or 3D design is selected, by subscribing to the [SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/#selection-changed-event)
- extract metadata of any individual design element using the [viewer.getProperties](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v7/reference/Viewing/Viewer3D/#getproperties-dbid-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) method, and see if it perhaps contains any property with its text content

You could try something like this:

```js
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.SELECTION_CHANGED_EVENT, function () {
    const selectedIds = viewer.getSelection();
    if (selectedIds.length === 1) {
        viewer.getProperties(selectedIds[0], function (result) {
            for (const prop of result.properties) {
                console.log(prop.displayName, prop.displayValue);
                // see if any of the properties of the element contains its text content
            }
        });
    }
});
```